# Declared const variable not visible in useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I am working through the following code:

`index.js`

```
import React, {useRef, useState, useEffect} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import AddAPhotoTwoTone from '@material-ui/icons/AddAPhotoTwoTone'
import backImg from "./background.png";

const Canvas = (props) => {
  const canvas = useRef(null);
  const image = useRef(null);
  const xLoc = useState(props.backImg.width/2)
  const yLocTop = useState(props.backImg.height/2)
  const yLocBottom = useState(props.backImg.height/2)

  useEffect(() => {
    const ctx = canvas.current.getContext("2d");
    image.current.onload = () => {
      ctx.drawImage(image.current, 0, 0);            
      ctx.font = "20px Courier";
      ctx.textAlign = "center";
      console.log(xLoc)
      ctx.fillText(props.textTop, xLoc, yLocTop);
      ctx.textAlign = "center";
      ctx.fillText(props.textBottom, xLoc, yLocBottom);
    };
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const ctx = canvas.current.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(image.current, 0, 0);
    // const xLoc = canvas.current.width/2
    // const yLocTop = canvas.current.height*.95
    // const yLocBottom = canvas.current.height*0.05
    ctx.font = "20px Courier";
      ctx.textAlign = "center";
      ctx.fillText(props.textTop, xLoc, yLocTop);
      ctx.textAlign = "center";
      ctx.fillText(props.textBottom, xLoc, yLocBottom);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <canvas ref={canvas} width={props.backImg.width} height={props.backImg.height} />
      <img ref={image} src={props.backImg} hidden/>
    </div>
  );
};


function App() {  
  return (
    <div className="App">  
      <Canvas textTop="TEST 123" textBottom="TEST 456" backImg={backImg} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Why is the `console.log(xLoc)` within first `useEffect` printing `NaN`?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const ctx = canvas.current.getContext("2d");
    image.current.onload = () => {
      ctx.drawImage(image.current, 0, 0);            
      ctx.font = "20px Courier";
      ctx.textAlign = "center";
      console.log(xLoc)
      ctx.fillText(props.textTop, xLoc, yLocTop);
      ctx.textAlign = "center";
      ctx.fillText(props.textBottom, xLoc, yLocBottom);
    };
  });
```

Sandbox code is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-microservice-xdsj7?fontsize=14)

Edit:

Even with properly configured `useState`, it returns NaN on console.

Comment: I dont think you are using `useState()` properly. Should be declaring 2 const's by destructuring the array that useState returns... `const [pieceOfState, setterFuncToUpdatePieceOfState] = useState(defaultValueForPieceOfState);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`useState()` returns an array. The first element is the state-value and the second is its state-updating function. You need to destructure the output like so.

Needs to be

```
const [xLoc, setxLoc] = useState(props.backImg.width/2)
const [yLocTop, setyLocTop] = useState(props.backImg.height/2)
const [yLocBottom, setyLocBottom] = useState(props.backImg.height/2)
```

Thus whatever you pass in to `useState()` will be the initial value.

Additionally. The problem is that the `props.backImg` is simply a string. It does not have any object properties like `.width`, and `.height`. To actually have access to those values, you need to first use that image as a `src` inside an `img` tag.

Then the `img` tag has access to the `onLoad` event-listener. With an event-handler, we can access the object properties mentioned. 
In sense, we first need to render the image on the screen, but that doesn't happen until we render the Canvas component, so there is no need to pass in those props from App. See sandbox for more details.

See sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-night-djzmr

Comment: It still prints Nan

Comment: You get NaN when you try to divide a non-num type by a number. Possibly check if (props.backImg.height) is a number before dividing it? @Zanam

Comment: Can you please see in the sandbox link why I am not able to get the dimensions? Or should I start a new thread?

Comment: @Zanam yeah I took some time to look at it. The problem is that the props.backImg is simply a string. It does not have any object properties like .width, and .height. To actually have access to those values, you need to first use that image as a src inside an img tag. Then the img tag has access to the onLoaded event-listener. Where we now can you the object properties mentioned. See sandbox for more details. In sense, there is no point passing the properties as props when we first need to render the image on the screen :)